# HP 8440p BIOS upgrade via Windows PE

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

An HP 8440p is outfitted with Ubuntu.  The goal is to [upgrade the BIOS](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/closure/hp-elitebook-8440p-notebook-pc/4095872?ssfFlag=true&sku=) from 68CCu V F.24 to version F.60 Rev. A.  I would like to avoid bricking a HP 8440p.

The BIOS upgrade file is a Windows Exe.  Is it possible or precedence to boot the laptop with a Windows PE USB stick and upgrade the BIOS with the sp73930.exe file from the command line?

If not, what are the options, not including installing Windows and running the executable?

It would be nice to able to avoid installing Windows, just to upgrade the BIOS.

Comment: "Is it possible or precedence to boot the laptop with a Windows PE" - No

Comment: [While you can't use WinPE there is a solution to your problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu). If none of those solutions work you should update and [edit] your question.

Comment: Check the HP Site carefully. Lenovo offers both Windows EXE BIOS and also, bootable USB Key to update BIOS. I should think HP would offer both.

Comment: HP says you can create a bootable usb ket to upgrade the bios for that model>>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8440p-notebook-pc/4095872

Comment: You should be able to use a Windows machine, which I happen to know you own, to create the flash drive that can be used to update the firmware. The file you download, sp73930.exe, is just a self-extracting archive.